# Docker - cannot build simple dotnet webapi container: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2 error

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, docker-build

I've created a simple .NET Core 3.0 web API. In the project directory, I have a Dockerfile that looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# copy over csproj and restore nuget packages
COPY DockerWebApiSandbox.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else over into the same directory as the last copy step
# and run the publish step to build and gather output
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o output

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerWebApiSandbox.dll"]
```

When running `docker build -t dockerwebapisandbox .` from the working directory of my project, I see a failure on step 9 of 10 (third COPY command):

> COPY failed: stat
>   /var/lib/docker/overlay2/f6f3391827aef74f1dab5716635a9119ae250ae94a216bbc0bc7b47c4030d60a/merged/app/out:
>   no such file or directory

When searching what the community was saying about this error, I found a suggestion [here](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1396). The suggestion mentions screening into the VM, but this command fails, given that the `com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/` directory does not exist where it's being expected. The screen command suggested looks like this: `$ screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty`

Other than trying the suggestion from the link above, I've tried uninstalling Docker and Docker Desktop altogether, in addition to the "Factory Reset" option provided in Docker Desktop.

FWIW, I am running MacOS Mojave. TIA for anyone who has suggestions.

Comment: Does the `RUN ... -o output` command create a directory `/app/output`, as distinct from the `/app/out` you're trying to `COPY` in the second stage?

Comment: `COPY --from=build-env /app/out .` should be changed to `COPY --from=build-env /app/output .` because you are publishing to directory named "output"

Comment: oof, yes you both are absolutely right.. thank you for finding such a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same error in Node. I was resolve using

```
COPY . .
```